# Days are not translated in the default language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localized

I am generating days like this:

```
(1..days_in_month(year, month)).each do |day|
  calendar << Day.new(day, day_from_date(format_day(day), month, year))
end
```

And then I access their names in the show page:

```
<% @calendar.each_with_index do |d, i| %>       
   <tr>
   <td><%= d.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

The days are in English despite having set the default language in French.

**application.rb**

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

**config/locales/fr.yml**

```
fr:
  date:
   abbr_day_names:
  - dim
  - lun
  - mar
  - mer
  - jeu
  - ven
  etc.
```

Console output:

```
2.1.5 :001 > I18n.locale
=> :fr
```

Why aren't the days translated in French?

**EDIT:**

Since it's a project I had to take over, I tried to look for a documentation for the `Day` class. I found a `local` documentation page that explains that `Day` "represents a day as a number and a name". It doesn't seem to be coming from an official documentation.

Comment: You have to use `I18n.localize` to translate the dates (shortcut `l`, as for `t` and `translate`). Something like `<%= l(your_date) %>`

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
`Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. #<ActivityHelper::Day:0x007fc0b4c153f0 @number=1, @name="Sunday"> given.`
I don't understand that error because my variable is only composed of `Days`.

Comment: Is `Day` a custom class you create by yourself ? If not, can you link me the documentation about it ? I can't find it online :/

Comment: Nope. See original post. I think I'm gonna have to manually translate the days.

Answer (score 1):

You can eventually translate the day names like this:

```
<% @calendar.each_with_index do |d, i| %>       
   <tr>
   <td><%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[d.number] %></td>
<% end %>
```

This implies that the attribute `number` of the `Day` records represent the "day index" in a 7 days week.

Comment: Well it does, but it would have been better to have a "day index" on a given month. Here I'm only having "monday, tuesday, [...], saturday" and the rest doesn't appear. And it's the same days for every month, which is obviously incorrect. That was a good idead though!

However I'm sure I'm gonna find a workaround with your solution. I'll update the topic asap.

Comment: Does the `number` attribute holds the day's number in the month? Like today would be `Day @number=25 @name=Wednesday` ? Where do you store the month?

Comment: Yes it does. The month is stored in another variable, independent from the `Days`.

Comment: You could use `Date.new(your_year, your_month, day.number)` to create a Date object (localizable with I18n)

Comment: Seems a bit overkill but it works! I just need to find the index of a month from its name. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't start this project, and amending some of its code might cause some problems. However it is indeed not very optimized.